# How to change DEM's gradient colour?

Tags: qgis, color, dem, style

I'm a newbie about GIS.
I'm from Italy and I've got a *.tif file of my region.
I've loaded it has raster but I have a question:

The dem has a gradient colour magenta.
How change this colour to typical "blu-green-yellow-brow" of Greografic representation?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The best plugin to use to do colour ramps on rasters is the `1-band raster color table v1.10` plugin.  Found in the plugin installer under the same name.

[image]

Comment: mmm it seems useful..i i can't find it yet

Comment: what a idiot! I didn't know how install plugins.
Now I've discovered.
Forgive me! Thanks

Comment: I looked in plug-in installer (QGIS 1.8.x) and cannot find 1-band raster color table. I looked at official repository for plug-ins and do not see it. Has it been discontinuted in the year and a half since the answer above?

Answer (score 1):

you can check out More Color Ramps for QGIS with [Colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/), [here](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/more-color-ramps-for-qgis/) from user @underdark.

you can add your color code following xml file for qgis style manager..

> If you want to use them, just import the following XML file into QGIS Style Manager:
>
> https://github.com/anitagraser/QGIS-resources/tree/master/symbols

[image: colorramp]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: these don't work for raster layers.  Only vectors.

Comment: ah! it doesn't work for rasters, so it's not useful for me. I'd like to change my tif...a raster file

Comment: oh sorry, i didnt consider for raster...

Comment: actually, you can use Colorbrewer ramps, but you have to do it via the Colorbrewer website and the 1-band color table plugin mentioned in Nathan W's answer. Export the color map from Colorbrewer using simple copy 'n paste, then in the plugin, choose the *ColorBrewer* palette, and paste in the dialog that comes up.

Comment: This functionality should really be part of core QGIS, not hidden in a plugin...