# How to classify/style rasters correctly?

Tags: qgis, raster, classification

I am using a GeoTiff raster data and trying to classify it. I was wondering what are the techniques that I can use in QGIS to do this?

The raster I have looks like

[image]

but I tried the reclassify tool in ArcMap and it looks like this

[image]

Now I wish do the similar classification using QGIS and I was able to acheive it by adding 9 entries in the Generate new Color map and clicking classify and applying it to the map. The image looks like this,

[image]

I again tried going to the Transparent tab and found that the No data value is -3.4e+38 and then clicked on Apply. Nothing changed. I then selected the Band1 in the Transparent band and then applied and the entire map disappears. Is it possible if I can display it in the same manner as the ArcMap's output?

Comment: Is the raster a weather map tile as you have shown, or is it just the red-blue-green overlay?

Comment: it is actually a species map

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Select the identify tab (an arrow with an "i")
2. Select the black extent box to capture the value
3. Right-click on your raster layer, select "properties"
4. In the "Style" tab, select the color map you would like to display,
   select "Apply"
5. Move to the "Transparency" tab and add the value you captured in
   step 2 to the "No Data Value" box and select "apply"

These steps will apply your settings to the layer properties only--they will not be permanent.

If you need to reclassify your raster into discrete steps, try using the raster calculator, here are two links to get you started: [GIS.se](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/27988/8104) & [GIS.se2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17712/8104) . Also, check out the 1-band raster color table for a [different color ramp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/26362/8104).

Comment: ok so i tried to do the following. I did change the colormap but the problem is that there are quite a bit of varying values. Is there some way the properties color tab can import them from the raster layer? I did try to load colormap from the band but it failed saying, `The color map for the band 1 failed to load`. There is only one band in the raster.

Comment: @Sam007 Post edited to address comments

Comment: When I go to the transparency tab, the value that I need to copy and paste in the No data value is already present and when I click apply everything disappears. Everything goes white. Any idea why??

Comment: Also I tried to install the raster calculator, but I am receiving the following error, 
`Couldn't import Python module 'pyparsing'. Without it you won't be able to run RasterCalc.`

Comment: I think I see your problem now--it looks like your raster dataset is binary, or consisting of two values.  When you set the "black" to transparent the "white" blends in with the background.  Try setting the white to a different color.  By the way, if your raster is in fact binary, you will not be able to produce the color gradient like you see in the second image.

Comment: I am sorry the previous rasters were not the correct one. I updated the question with the right one

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the best way to create the raster classification. I understand that I did not provide the fact in the question that after I reclassify the raster I required it to be added to the Geoserver and viewed on an application. The above raster classification works fine but the problem was that it losses it's original data and acquires the newly assigned value. This defeats my purpose as I do not wish to change the pixel values or the data in the raster.

Therefore I found the means of creating SLD raster symbolizer and assigning it to the raster that has been added to the Geoserver in it's raw form. This is the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html) of creating the SLD for raster symbolizer.

Comment: whoa downvoted why?